# Filtering playa and stash by categories

Tags: categories, stash, gwcode-categories

I am trying to filter a list by category, with each staff member listed beneath it. Here is my code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="offices" entry_id="23" dynamic="no"}
{office_staff}
    {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" style="linear" entry_count="yes" parse="inward"}
        {exp:stash:append_list name="city1_staff_{cat_id}" save="yes" scope="site"}
            {stash:title}{title} - {cat_id}<br/>{/stash:title}
        {/exp:stash:append_list}
    {/exp:gwcode_categories}
{/office_staff}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:channel:categories channel="staff" style="linear"}
<h2>{category_name} - {category_id}</h2>
<ul>
    {exp:stash:get_list name="city1_staff_{category_id}"}
        <li>
            <h3>{title}</h3>
        </li>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
</ul>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

The categories are listing properly, and looking at mustash, it looks like the lists are being generated correctly, but for some reason the stash get_list isn't populating in the second code block. I am sure it is something simple, but its got me going in circles. Maybe someone has a clear view of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top of my head, its a parse order thing.
Try wrapping your exp:categories tag with

```
{exp:stash:parse process='end'}{exp:categories}...{/exp;categories}{/exp:stash:parse}
```